# How to load this file given a specific Backbone route?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am currently working on a single page web application and new to Backbone.

I have a list of navigations for my page and each is within a separate PHP/HTML file. What I want is to load this file given a specific route (e.g. `/contacts` will load *contacts.php* or *contacts.html*).

How to do that?

Comment: More or less the logic of what I want goes this way.                     var route = Backbone.Router.extend({ 'contact' : 'contactUsHandler', contactUsHandler : function() { //render the template contactus.php or contactus.html  }  });

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found any forum or discussion relating to this however the process of rendering a template from a backbone route can be done through

```
var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes : {
            '/contact' : 'contactUsHandler'
        },
        home : function() {
            var url = urlToRequestServerToRenderATemplate,
                that = this;
            $.ajax({
               type : 'GET',
               url  : url,
               success : function(response) {
                 //response should contain the html rendered from server
                 var contactView = new contactView(); 
                 contactView.render(response.html);
               }
            })
        }
    })

var contactView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : '#main-container',
        render : function(html) {
            this.$el.html(html);
        }
});
```